# Gray color from button xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, styles

I write in Xamarin.Forms PCL. I set BorderRadius from My Button, but if I set disabled it or press on it, show gray border without Border Radius:

[image]

I want to clear gray border or set it border radius.

Comment: can you post your XAML?

Comment: I have not xaml

Comment: I don't know I can change this gray color in PCL xaml ?

Comment: how do you create your UI, with c#? Post your ContentPage

Comment: `Button myButton = new Button{
                BackgroundColor = Color.Orange,
                BorderRadius = 10
            };`

Comment: I try with an Android Emulator 6.0 API 23 but I don't see this problem. When you click the button, it has a gray shadow with rounded corners. Can you post your full code? which Android version do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137859/discussion-between-alessandro-caliaro-and-dmitrii-kurylev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607 (Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) version 10.0.14393.0), `generic.xaml` includes resources that you can use to modify the colors of a control in different visual states without modifying the control template. In apps that target this software development kit (SDK) or later, modifying these resources is preferred to setting properties such as Background and Foreground. For more info, see the Light-weight styling section of the [Styling controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox#remarks).

If you override this in your Application.Resources(Xamarin.UWP Client Project) as below:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="White" />
</Application.Resources>
```

It should take affect everywhere.

[image]

Comment: Thanks and there is something similar for android?

Comment: As far as I know it is uwp's feature.